# Какие методы протокола HTTP можно использовать для отправки данных формы на сервер?

Tags: html, http

Какие методы протокола HTTP можно использовать для отправки данных формы на сервер?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GET и POST

Comment: ...PUT, DELETE. все зависит от сервера и логики.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, спецификация HTML не позволяет создавать формы, отправляющие данные иначе, чем через GET или POST. PUT и DELETE реализуются через XMLHttpRequest. А судя по вопросу до различных оберток вопрошающему очень далеко.

Comment: Судя по вопросу, человек сдает экзамен по HTML.